# Difference between today and a date with negative numbers

Tags: google-sheets-dates, date

I need to calculate the difference in days between today and a set date allowing also negative differences.

Basically it's the shipping date for each order and how many days we have left till each shipping date or how many days we are running late once the shipping date has passed.

With `datediff` it stops counting once today is bigger than the shipping date.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried substracting both values? You could format it as number if it shows like a date in year 1899.

[image]